# JS - items of array unavailable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a simple array in JS - it looks like this (simplified):

```
api.call("GetList", {
...
}, function (codesResults) {
  var codesList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fetchedData.length; i++) {
    ...
    codesList.push(res[0].codeNumber);
    ...
  }
});
```

When trying to debug the array:

```
console.log('codesList:', codesList);
```

[image]

When I try `console.log(codesList.length);` -> **0**.

When I try `console.log(codesList[0]);` -> **undefined**.

What am I overlooking that I am unable to access the elements of the array?

Comment: where are you inspecting that? inside the async callback or outside?

Comment: Is there a code after these lines presented that is editing the codesList array?

Comment: Do a `console.log(typeof codesList)` where you're getting undefined. My guess is it's a promise object.

Comment: @JoelHager - it says `object`.

Comment: @DanielA.White the `console` statements are outside of the callback.

Comment: If it's an object, you don't access it like an array. That isn't an *index* but a key. Try this: `codesList["0"]`

Comment: @JoelHager already tried that - same result.

Comment: Can you give us all of the call? you have a `...` in there. There might be an issue there.

Comment: It seems like it would actually be `res["0"].codeNumber`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `codesList` is declared (with the `var` keyword) inside your function, which means that it has local scope.

When you inspect in the console, you probably tried accessing it globally, where it is `undefined`.

Declare the variable outside the function, maybe at the top of your code, so that it is accessible from every part of your code and the console.